# Controlling the unity ui slider via script

Tags: user-interface, audio, unity-game-engine, uislider, volume

I have a simple question: how does one go about controlling the UI Slider in Unity via code? I can control a GUI slider quite easily, but I'd prefer to work with the UI slider that can be assigned in the hierarchy.

I have a few scripts that control volume and audio timeline scrubbing (moving the slider to a certain point in an audio track) that work great, but I want to assign these scripts to a Unity UI slider.

I think I am missing something pretty easy, but have spent too much time trying to get this right. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Have you had a look at the Tutorial for Sliders yet? And the Scripting API?

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Slider.html
http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/ui/ui-slider

The Slider has a OnValueChange eventHandler and there you can for example directly drag in your AudioListener (attached to the main Camera) or the script you want to call. [image: Screenshot]
To add more calls just press the + ;)

Good Luck, hope that helps.